# how to each data above is given |=====|?

Tags: php

I don't know how to make every data array above it given |======|

```
<?php

$data = [21, 231, 12121, 3332, 444444, 2212, 1, 234, 5523, 312];

$length = max(array_map('strlen', $data));

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    echo "+======+";
    
}
    
echo "\n";

foreach ($data as $value => $v) {
    $diff = $length - strlen($v);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; $i++) {
        echo '*';
        
    }
    
    if (($value + 1) % 4 == 0) {
      echo $v ."|" . "\n";
    } else {
      echo $v;
    }
    
    echo '|';
}

?>
```

ouput currently :

[image: output-current]

I hope my output this :

[image: hope-output :]

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Post the actual text. But more importantly, also talk about what you _already tried_ to fix this, since you clearly know how to write PHP, so: what have you tried already?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = [21, 231, 12121, 3332, 444444, 2212, 1, 234, 5523, 312];
$columns = 4;

$digitsLength = max(array_map('strlen', $data));

$groupedData = array_chunk($data, $columns);

foreach ($groupedData as $row)
{
    echo str_repeat ('|' .  str_repeat('=', $digitsLength), $columns) . "|\n";

    // uncomment the next to draw a table with all columns in the last row as well
    //$row = array_pad($row, $columns, str_repeat(' ', $digitsLength));
    
    foreach ($row as $col)
        echo '|' . str_pad($col, $digitsLength, '*', STR_PAD_LEFT) . (next ($row) === false ? "|\n" : '');
}
```